# pass environment variable when use `kubectl apply -f file.yaml`

Tags: kubernetes

Can I pass environment variable when use `kubectl apply -f file.yaml` like `kubectl apply -f file.yaml -env HOST=dev.api.host.com`?

Because I have a file yaml, and I need to run in two pipelines, in one case to use host for production and in another case to use host for developlemnt.

I don't want to use two different files, I want to use one file, where I'll replace the host.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how you should update environment variables in deployment yaml.

```
export TAG="1.11.1"
export NAME=my-nginx
envsubst < deployment.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend a different solution:

In Kubernetes you can use [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) and [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) to store your configuration.

There are multiple ways how to do it.
You could for example split development and production in 2 namespaces, if they should run in one cluster.
Then you can put a ConfigMap with your host configuration in each namespace.
When you deploy the same deployment to different namespaces, they'll find their appropriate ConfigMap and load it.

---

If you want to go the way of replacing it, a simple search-and-replace in your file would work.

In your file.yml specify an environment variable like this

```
    env:
    - name: HOST
      value: %%HOST%%
```

And in your pipeline replace it with the appropriate value

```
sed -i -e "s#%%HOST%%#http://whatever#" file.yml;
```

Comment: how to use secrets in the deployment.yaml?

Answer (score 4):

`kubectl` does not provide any such facility to pass environment variables on the fly. Like @Pampy mentioned, other way would be by using `ConfigMaps and Secrets`. In case you are going to use same resource specs in two different environments, I would suggest to go with [Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#quickstart). Helm provides an easy way to package Kubernetes resource yamls in an efficient way. It consists of `values.yaml` which can be used separately depending on the environment you are planning to use. If still you want to insert values on the fly then, check this [kubectl cheat sheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#creating-objects)